# Azure AD B2C sign out session from iOS native app

Tags: swift, azure-ad-b2c, single-sign-out

we developed an iOS application using swift and we integrated the app with Azure AD B2C, the sign out and sign in process are done via user flows, but we are having trouble performing a successfully sign out process.

We read in Microsoft documentation that we need to perform a GET request to an end_session endpoint so we can invalidate the user Azure AD session: [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#sign-out) and [text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request).

We implemented this GET request, but nothing happened, the session was still active.

We didn't find any other resource for native applications, so we are not sure what needs to be done to implement a correctly sign out process.

Comment: "After logout, the user is redirected to the URI specified in the post_logout_redirect_uri parameter, regardless of the reply URLs that you specify for the application." Did you configure the parameter?